# Fix the Row height of shairpoint list

Tags: list-view-web-part

You guys have always helped me and I hope I get my query solved this time too.

My ShairPoint List have one multiline field with long text which is making my list view irregular row hight

I want all row hight shall be same and view should be uniform

Please help, if anybody is providing the code to webpart please describe where shall I insert it and I am using SP2010

thanks a ton in advance

Comment: SharePointDesigner2010 has view support on lists. Download it, connect to your SharePoint site using designer and then you will be able to edit row heights using view pane.

https://www.microsoft.com/tr-tr/download/details.aspx?id=24309

Comment: i have Shairpoint designer 2010    can you guide me more on this

Comment: I have Shairpoint designer 2010 can you guide me more on this

Comment: Can you check this link?

https://smallbusiness.chron.com/change-width-columns-sharepoint-47331.html